# Kafka ->Spark streaming -> Hbase. Task not serializable Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING

Tags: java, hbase, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to write data that is produced from Kafka commandline producer for some topic.

I am facing problem and unable to proceed. Below is my code which I am creating it as a jar and running through spark-submit on spark-shell.

Am I doing wrong inside `foreachRDD()` ? What is wrong with  `SparkKafkaDemo$2.call(SparkKafkaDemo.java:63)` line in below error message?

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaDemo").setMaster("local").setSparkHome("/Users/kvk/softwares/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.4");

            JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Duration.seconds(1));

            int numThreads = 2;
            Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            topicMap.put("nonview", numThreads);

            JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
                    KafkaUtils.createStream(jsc, "localhost", "ViewConsumer", topicMap);

            JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                    return tuple2._2();
                }
            });

            lines.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {
                                 @Override
                                 public Void call(JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD) throws Exception {
                                     JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> hbasePuts = stringJavaRDD.mapToPair(
                                             new PairFunction<String, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put> call(String line) throws Exception {

                                                     Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("Rowkey" + Math.random()));
                                                     put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("firstFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("firstColumn"), Bytes.toBytes(line+"fc"));
                                                     return new Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, Put>(new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put);
                                                 }
                                             });

                                     // save to HBase- Spark built-in API method
                                     hbasePuts.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration());
                                     return null;
                                 }
                             }
            );
            jsc.start();
            jsc.awaitTermination();
```

Error :

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "SparkKafkaDemo" --master local /Users/kvk/IntelliJWorkspace/HbaseDemo/HbaseDemo.jar

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)

at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)

at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1623)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:286)

at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.mapToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:113)

at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.mapToPair(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)

at SparkKafkaDemo$2.call(SparkKafkaDemo.java:63)

at SparkKafkaDemo$2.call(SparkKafkaDemo.java:60)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:311)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:311)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)

at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:176)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)

at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)

at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:175)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.ensureState(Job.java:283)

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.toString(Job.java:452)

at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2847)

at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)

at scala.StringContext.standardInterpolator(StringContext.scala:122)

at scala.StringContext.s(StringContext.scala:90)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:103)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visitSerializable(SerializationDebugger.scala:158)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$SerializationDebugger.visit(SerializationDebugger.scala:99)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.find(SerializationDebugger.scala:58)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:39)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)

at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:80)

at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)

... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a serialization

```
sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay for the reply. Actually, I modified the code by passing the object of concrete class that implements the PairFunction interface. That solved the issue. But, still I face an issue as my code works properly for line count (similar to word count where it calculates unique line count from the messages) but not hbase insertion. I could clearly see the blocks of RDDs coming in to spark from kafka cluster, but hbase insertion some how not happening. May I know what could be the issue?  I am running the master with more than 1 thread.

Comment: See at this link. http://pastebin.com/yAKfVfuK for the hbase insertion code. Am I missing some thing or any wrong. I am not seeing any error but spark continuously receiving messages but not writing to hbase.